# Is there difference in string concatenation using shortand operator?

Tags: c++, string, shorthand

I tried appending character to end of the string using + operator to a coding problem .That solution was giving memory limit exceeded. Then I saw solutions using += to append character. Is there any difference between the two in case of time complexity or memory complexity ?

Example - My solution

```
string arrangeWords(string text) {
 text[0] = text[0] + 32;
 text = text + ' ';
 string temp = "";
 map < int, vector < string >> mp;
 for (char c: text) {
  if (c != ' ')
   temp = temp + c; //---Notice this  line
  else {
   mp[temp.size()].push_back(temp);
   temp = "";
  }
 }
 string res = "";
 for (auto it: mp)
  for (auto j: it.second)
   res = res + j + ' '; //----Notice this line

 res[0] = toupper(res[0]);
 return res.substr(0, res.size() - 1);
}
```

Accepted Solution -

```
string arrangeWords(string text) {
 text[0] += 32;
 text += ' ';
 string temp = "";
 map < int, vector < string >> mp;
 for (char c: text) {
  if (c != ' ')
   temp += c; //Notice this line change
  else {
   mp[temp.size()].push_back(temp);
   temp = "";
  }
 }
 string res = "";
 for (auto it: mp)
  for (auto j: it.second)
   res += j + ' '; //Notice this line change

 res[0] = toupper(res[0]);
 return res.substr(0, res.size() - 1);
}
```

Comment: Avoid magical number: `text[0] = text[0] + 32;` should be `text[0] = tolower(text[0]);` (more readable and is portable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`temp = temp + c;` creates a temporary `temp + c` (which would probably require (slow) allocation) before to assign to `temp`. (Complexity is O(n))

`temp += c;` reuse buffer if large enough (complexity O(1)), else reallocation should be done (and then, it would be "similar" to above method) (complexity O(n)). (amortized complexity is `O(1)`)

In addition, less allocation occurs, less chance to have fragmented memory.

Comment: What is the normal buffer size for string ? Is it dependent on language used?

Comment: @Ash • compiler implementation detail.  You can check using [`s.capacity()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/capacity) on a given string.  If you know ahead of time how much space you need, say 10,000, you can [`s.reserve(10000)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/reserve).